# "herald" as as intransitive verb?

Tags: transitive-verbs

The Lost Symbol, page 537, the author writes: "..., mankind will at last unearth the Word and herald in a wondrous new age of enlightenment."

I checked the Cambridge dictionary and "herald" is a transitive verb. So, why is there a preposition after the verb? Is "herald in" a phrasal verb?

Isn't it more correct to say "herald a wondrous new age of enlightenment."?

Could anyone please elaborate?

Comment: OALD, CED, Macmillan, AH Roget's Thesaurus and Collins (and UsingEnglish.com) all include 'usher in' as a transitive multi-word verb (I think they all use the term 'phrasal verb', but that has conflicting definitions). 'Announce' / 'be the first sign of a new season (in any sense)' / 'cause important changes to start happening' are different related senses. 'Herald in' is at least 'partly synonymous' with these senses, and is formally the same; the only reason I can think of its non-inclusion as a MWV in these publications is that it is dated and used far more rarely....

Comment: Yes; [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ushered+in%2Cheralded+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cushered%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheralded%20in%3B%2Cc0) would seem to indicate that it _is_ used far more rarely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Free Dictionary defines [*herald*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/herald) as

> 1. A person who carries or proclaims important news; a messenger.
> 2. One that gives a sign or indication of something to come; a harbinger: The crocus is a herald of spring.

Just as the crocus is a *herald* of spring, the flower can also *herald in* the season. To *herald in* something is to announce the beginning of something important. It's often used for holidays, the four seasons, and anything the writer considers important or eventful.

> Headline: **Fair Final Days of Summer, But Rain to [*Herald in*](http://knkx.org/post/fair-final-days-summer-rain-herald-fall-sunday) Fall on Sunday** | 20 Sep 2013 ·Right on cue, typical fall rains will usher in the official start of autumn with the equinox on Sunday.
>
> 25 Jan 2018 · The first snowdrops appear here in Somerset around the end of January and they are a sign to [*herald in*](http://www.middlewickholidaycottages.co.uk/snowdrops-somerset/) the end of Winter.
>
> An exposition of the Sacred Tooth Relic of the Lord Buddha will be held from 6 to 16 March 2009, to [*herald in*](http://www.asiantribune.com/?q=node/15789) a new era of peace and unity in Sri Lanka.
>
> 19 Oct 2016 · It would be great to see the New Year's Eve fireworks back to [*herald in*](http://www.theherald.com.au/story/4237502/walk-in-our-shoes-before-passing-comment/) 2017.

In the first example, the writer is using *herald in* and *usher in* to mean the same thing, but a metaphor from the theater is less colorful than one where anyone who's ever seen a film set in the Middle Ages is going to imagine some young man in red tights with a trumpet, i.e., a herald. Thus one often sees *herald in* in headlines commanding your attention.